# Maven Plugin to read xml properties file

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

Just a quick question.

Does anyone knows an XML Properties file plugin , like we had XML 
property file in ANT

```
<property name='foo' value='bar'> 

<property name='foo1' value='${foo}/bar1'> 

<property name='foo2' value='bar2'>
```

Thanks in Advance

Note: I have an idea of using other ways of declaring properties in maven/ in pom.xml. Just want to know this exact way of implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Properties Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) may meet your goal. The [properties:read-project-properties](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html) will reads property files and stores them as project properties as the following example:-

```xml
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>path/to/my_properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Please note, the `path/to/my_properties` is a simple properties file which contains key-value pair as the following example: -

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
....
```

Regarding to the properties above, we can refer them via Maven by using `${key1}` or `${key2}`.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Interesting... Does this actually support properties in XML files...?

Comment: @carlspring As far as I test, the XML properties file is not supported.

Comment: The `properties.xml` is in a different format. Have a look at an example here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-tiger02254/index.html . I think Vijay will be better off with writing a plugin.

Comment: plugin properties-maven-plugin:read-project-properties is not working for xml properties file. I am looking for some thing that loads properties from say properties.xml

Comment: I apologize for the invalid answer.

Comment: +1 @CharleeChitsuk I'm a beginner in maven. so every suggestion is a valid answer for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk: I wouldn't say it's an invalid answer, just not the plugin he really needs. I think that regular properties stored in the format supported by the Java API will work (haven't tried it). However, he is using Ant-based ones and those seem to have a completely different format. While it is not what he is looking for, I suggest you keep the answer, as it could be valid for the case where people have proper Java XML properties files.

Comment: @Vijay: Perhaps you could try converting those properties.xml files into standard ones as supported by the Java API and give it a go.

Comment: I have no luck with standard Java XML properties files, either. It seems the files _must_ be in the "key=value" format to work with this plugin